# Blender 2.8 Transform stretch problem

Tags: transforms, edges, extrude

Whenever I try to transform any edges, all of the surrounding edges will raise up even if they are not connected.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens and/or know how to turn it off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the entire mesh move in this model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187066/why-does-the-entire-mesh-move-in-this-model)

Comment: You will get a much more detailed answer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got `Proportional Editing` turned on - you might have accidentally activated it with the hotkey <kbd>O</kbd>, or by clicking the small blue circle button just above the timeline, a little to the right of center. You can turn it off by pressing <kbd>O</kbd> or clicking the button again. That should restore the behavior you're used to.
[image]
That being said, proportional editing can be a really useful tool, so if you're not familiar with it, I'd definitely recommend reading up on it!